# WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST で指定できる言語の定数一覧

Tags: winapi

Auto Hot Key を用いて入力言語の切り替えを行いたく
こちらのサイトを参考にして
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/81886-solved-autohotkey-script-input-language/
以下のスクリプトでロシア語に変更できることはわかりました。

```
^j::
  PostMessage, 0x50, 0, 0x4190419,, A ; 0x50 is WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST
Return
```

それで他にも `EN: "0x4090409"`, `UA: "-0xF57FBDE"` などが載っていたのですが、それ以外の言語がわかりませんでした。

またMSDNの`WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST`の項目に何かあるかと思ったんですが情報まで辿りつけませんでした。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/ms632630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

言語を指定するための定数一覧はどのように探せばよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

入力ロケール識別子(Input Locale Identifier)は`LoadKeyboardLayout`関数に[キーボードレイアウト識別子](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc766503%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)を渡せば求める事が出来ます。

C#であれば以下のようなコードになります。

```
var keyboard = "00000409"; // USキーボード
var id = LoadKeyboardLayout(keyboard, 1); // 0x04090409
```